How do i set a Variable to a specific line of a text document in powerShell?
i have a .txt file that has a list of numbers formatted like this:
1010
1020
1030
and I need PowerShell to set a variable to the first line, then set that same variable to the second line and so on.
I used something like this:
$num = Get-Content D:\bruteforce\list.txt | Select -first 1 | Select -first 1
And it works when it does the first number, but when it does the second line it sets the variable $num to the first 2 lines instead of only the second line by itself. so I just need something like this but it sets the variable to the first line then ONLY the second line and so on so if i had this list:
1
2
3
So it wound set the $num variable to 1 then 2 then 3, then add another variable to the end, so if i had a $word variable that was set to "hello" it would set the $num variable to:
1hello
2hello
3hello

Not sure if I completely understood, but I think this: $word = "hello"; switch -Regex -File "D:\bruteforce\list.txt" {"\S" {$_ + $word} default {$_} }

If you simply want to process the lines of your input file iteratively, do something like Get-Content D:\bruteforce\list.txt | ForEach-Object { $num = $_ + $word; <# work with $num #> }. Please clarify if that is the intent, by directly updating your question.

Share how you will use this variable

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use a little .NET Framework inside powershell. You can do this like;
[string]$numVariable = "hello"
$fullpath = "D:\bruteforce\list.txt"
if (Test-Path $fullpath)
{
    $lines = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines("D:\bruteforce\list.txt")
    foreach($line in $lines)
    {
        $numVariable = $line.ToString()+$yourVariable
    }
}

